# What's the cause for "PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES is too large and requires streaming" when using EWS Managed API?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

An application uses EWS Managed API to fetch and process large quantities of Exchange items. The items are loaded using `ExchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, propertySet)`.

During the items' processing, when a property of an item is being accessed, the following exception is thrown:

```
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException: Data is corrupt., The object data is corrupted. The value of property [0x1039001f] PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES is too large and requires streaming.
```

The only thing I could find so far is an advice to use `BindToItems()` instead of `LoadPropertiesForItems()`, but I didn't try it out yet (I cannot reproduce the issue consistently).

My question, then, is: How do I do the streaming mentioned in the error (if that is what I need to do at all)?

**Update** (added some code examples)

```
var basicPropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, ItemSchema.LastModifiedTime, ItemSchema.ParentFolderId)
{
    new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x300B, MapiPropertyType.Binary)
};

var detailsPropset = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Id, ItemSchema.LastModifiedTime, ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived,
    ItemSchema.ParentFolderId, EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, ItemSchema.Subject, EmailMessageSchema.From)
    {
        new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x300B, MapiPropertyType.Binary), ItemSchema.MimeContent
    };

var filter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection
    {
        new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.LastModifiedTime, modifiedSince),
        new SearchFilter.IsLessThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.LastModifiedTime, modifiedBefore),
        new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(ItemSchema.ItemClass, itemClass),
    };

var view = new ItemView(pageSize, 0, OffsetBasePoint.Beginning)
    {
        PropertySet = basicPropertySet
    };

    view.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.LastModifiedTime, SortDirection.Ascending);
// view.Offset is getting updated during the process

var items = exchangeService.FindItems(folderToScan.Id, searchFilter, view);

var ids = items.Select(item => item.Id).ToList();

exchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, detailedPropertySet);

foreach (var item in items)
{
    // verify properties are loaded, by simply accessing them
    // this is where the exception is thrown.
    itemx.From;
    item.LastModifiedTime;
    item.Id;
    item.MimeContent;
    item.Subject;
}
```

Comment: It really sounds like an issue in your code eg different property sets being used between finditems and LoadPropertiesForItems you really need to post your code as it will be obvious if that is the error to anybody looking. Streamable properties are those props greater then 512 KB which you need to use GetItem to retrieve (which LoadPropertiesForItems does)

Comment: @GlenScales Thanks for the comment! I'll add some code snippets in a bit.

Comment: I've added some excerpts from the code. It is true that we are using different property sets between FindItems and LoadPropertiesForItems, but most of the time, this works.

Comment: @GlenScales Updated. : )

Comment: Are you actually defining and using PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES I can't see that in your code. Basically you should avoid using PR_INTERNET_REFERENCES in FindItems because this property could grow beyond what FindItem can return based on the number or responses etc. On which line is it throwing the error ? the next thing would be to do some tracing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633676(v=exchg.80).aspx

Comment: It's the "verifying properties" block of code which "throws up". I'll add some more logs to be 100% sure which property cannot be loaded. My humble suspicion is that item.MimeContent cannot be loaded. However, I find it mysterious that it's failing after a LoadProperties() call, not FindItems().

Comment: Thanks, for the tip for tracing! I'm pretty new with this, and the first time I see that you can trace EWS requests!